# Magento 2 User Access Permission

Tags: magento2, admin, user-roles, access

I am developing a Store in Magento 2. I created an Admin Account at the time of installation of Magento 2. Later I tried to create another User (Who can only add product in the store) from Admin Panel and a User Role (Which has only product entry access). In this time I assigned Admin User to that specific role (Product entry).

Then I install a Magento 2 in local host and replaced all the data of `admin_user` , `authorization_role`, `authorization_rule` table of database to regain access of Admin User. But when I tried to login using that Admin User I am getting a Message  *You need more permissions to access this.* I attached a screenshot below. How can I get previous Admin User with previous Access?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastet option you have is to create a new admin and reset the previous user's permissions.

You can do it from command line.

Move to your Magento's root and type:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create \
    --admin-user="mynewuser" \
    --admin-password="mynewpassword" \
    --admin-email="john@doe.com" \
    --admin-firstname="MyName" \
    --admin-lastname="MyLastName"
```

This will create a new admin user with username `mynewuser` and password `mynewpassword`.

When you are in just fix your old admin user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the existing user name **"admin"** setting the following columns in **admin_user** table solves the issue for me,

**Columns:**

Failure Number - 0
first_failure - NULL
lock_expires  - NULL

**PHP MyAdmin:**

[image: Using PHP MyAdmin]

Answer (score 1):

**[ Magento 2.x.x ]**

***Note:- use mysqldump to back up your databases before doing anything further***

Step-1: Back up below Tables

```
    Table 1 :-  admin_user
    
    Table 2 :-  authorization_role
    
    Table 3 :-  authorization_rule
```

Step-2: truncate Above three Table using truncate command ( not using DELETE command )

```
truncate table [ Table Name ];
```

Step-3: insert new User in with All Roles , Run below three Command

1. This insert data into admin_user table

   ```
        INSERT INTO `admin_user` (`user_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `created`, `modified`, `logdate`, `lognum`, `reload_acl_flag`, `is_active`, `extra`, `rp_token`, `rp_token_created_at`, `interface_locale`, `failures_num`, `first_failure`, `lock_expires`, `refresh_token`) VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@gmail.com', 'admin', '45cf9053530ceb9fde49794d9e6d81fd2ce481b0136067986a5c9bc139a7d08f:FivE4hOQqPtW1xdE:2', '2019-07-23 10:48:31', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', 46, 0, 1, '{\"configState\":{\"contact_contact\":\"1\",\"web_default_layouts\":\"0\",\"web_default\":\"1\",\"web_secure\":\"1\",\"web_seo\":\"1\",\"web_unsecure\":\"1\",\"wishlist_wishlist_link\":\"1\",\"wishlist_email\":\"1\",\"wishlist_general\":\"1\",\"admin_emails\":\"0\",\"admin_startup\":\"0\",\"dev_front_end_development_workflow\":\"1\",\"dev_restrict\":\"0\",\"dev_debug\":\"1\",\"dev_template\":\"0\",\"sw_megamenu_general\":\"1\",\"newsletter_general\":\"1\",\"newsletter_subscription\":\"1\",\"dev_js\":\"0\",\"admin_security\":\"0\",\"admin_url\":\"0\",\"admin_dashboard\":\"0\",\"admin_captcha\":\"0\",\"sw_megamenu_custom_links\":\"1\",\"sw_megamenu_cat_labels\":\"1\",\"cms_wysiwyg\":\"1\",\"catalog_frontend\":\"1\",\"catalog_fields_masks\":\"0\",\"catalog_review\":\"1\",\"catalog_productalert\":\"1\",\"catalog_productalert_cron\":\"1\",\"catalog_placeholder\":\"1\",\"catalog_recently_products\":\"1\",\"catalog_product_video\":\"0\",\"catalog_price\":\"0\",\"catalog_layered_navigation\":\"1\",\"catalog_search\":\"0\",\"catalog_seo\":\"0\",\"catalog_navigation\":\"1\",\"catalog_downloadable\":\"1\",\"catalog_custom_options\":\"0\",\"layered_navigation_module\":\"1\",\"layered_navigation_general\":\"1\",\"carriers_flatrate\":\"1\",\"carriers_freeshipping\":\"1\",\"carriers_tablerate\":\"1\",\"carriers_temando\":\"1\",\"carriers_ups\":\"1\",\"carriers_usps\":\"1\",\"carriers_fedex\":\"1\",\"carriers_dhl\":\"1\",\"shipping_origin\":\"1\",\"shipping_shipping_policy\":\"1\",\"tax_vertex_settings\":\"1\",\"tax_classes\":\"1\",\"tax_calculation\":\"1\",\"tax_defaults\":\"1\",\"tax_display\":\"1\",\"tax_cart_display\":\"1\",\"tax_sales_display\":\"1\",\"tax_weee\":\"1\",\"tax_vertex_seller_info\":\"0\",\"tax_vertex_delivery_terms\":\"0\",\"tax_avaiable_shipping_product_codes\":\"0\",\"tax_vertex_logging\":\"0\",\"dev_grid\":\"0\",\"dev_static\":\"0\",\"dev_image\":\"0\",\"dev_css\":\"0\",\"dev_translate_inline\":\"0\",\"general_store_information\":\"1\",\"general_single_store_mode\":\"1\",\"general_locale\":\"1\",\"general_region\":\"1\",\"general_country\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_general_option\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_google_captcha\":\"1\",\"productinquiry_email_setting\":\"1\",\"trans_email_ident_general\":\"1\",\"product_attachment_general\":\"1\",\"product_attachment_display_configuration\":\"1\"}}', NULL, NULL, 'en_US', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   ```
2. This insert Data into authorization_role table

   INSERT INTO `authorization_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `user_type`, `role_name`) VALUES
   (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators'),
   (2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, '2', 'admin');
3. This insert Data into authorization_rule

   INSERT INTO `authorization_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `permission`) VALUES
   (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', NULL, 'allow');

Step-4: Run below Magento Command

```
    php bin/magento set:up;
    
    php bin/magento s:s:d -f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:f ;
    
    php bin/magento c:c ;
```

Step-5: Run your Admin login and try below username and password to login.

```
    username :- admin
    
    Password :- admin@123
```

if above username and password not working please create new admin user [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-add-admin-user-command-line.html)

Now your Administrators Role are Reset to default.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `authorization_role` and `authorization_role` tables were empty.

```
SELECT * FROM authorization_role;
Empty set (0.001 sec)

SELECT * FROM authorization_rule;
Empty set (0.001 sec)
```

Insert into authorization tables

```
INSERT INTO authorization_role (role_id, parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, user_type, role_name) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators');

INSERT INTO authorization_rule (rule_id, role_id, resource_id, privileges, permission) VALUES (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', null, 'allow');
```

Delete your existing admin user

```
DELETE FROM admin_user WHERE user_id = YOUR_USER_ID;
```

Create admin user again

```
bin/magento admin:user:create
```

**Reference:** [Magento 2: No Administrators role was found](https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-no-administrators-role-was-found-data-fixture-needs-to-be-run-while-creating-admin-user-from-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was because the users were not assigned any roles. So I created roles and assigned it to the users.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises when there is no association between a user account and the User ROLE, and when an account has been marked as inactive.